# SQL Server 2008 doesn't accept all text pasted to a cell

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table that contains a `ntext` column. I'm trying to edit the table from SQL Server Management Studio the problem is when I'm trying to paste html text into the `ntext` column it takes only the text up to the first newline char, however when I tried the same in another database on the same engine it accepts all the text I paste to it I tried to find the difference between the 2 DB but I found nothing, can any one help.

Comment: What are the 2 different database versions? E.g. 2008, 2008 R2, 2012. Also, can you please provide the HTML you are trying to paste.

Comment: Two issues here. First is using the GUI grid to edit data. It would be much easier and stable to use an update statement. The second issue is using the ntext datatype. This datatype has been deprecated since 2005. You should instead use (n)varchar(max). Since you state this is html you really don't need to support the extended character set as those are invalid html characters anyway. Just use varchar(max).

Comment: The problem is most likely not with the database, but with the GUI interface.  My guess would be that pasting text with a newline character is messing with the GUI and causing it to 'cut-off' your text there.  Try running the insert using an actual T-SQL statement and see what happens.  (Also, like Sean Lange said, you really shouldn't be using `ntext` if you have any way of going another route.)